# What is the grading of this report about Ibn Umar kissing a slave?

Tags: authenticity, slavery

“Narrated Ayoub bin Abdullah al-Lukhmi that ibn Umar said: ‘On the day of the Jalola battle I won a slave girl, her neck was like a silver ewe.’ Then ibn Umar added: ‘I couldn’t control myself, I immediately jumped on her and began kissing her, while the people were looking at me”

Answer (score 1):

This athar has been weakened by some scholars due to the criticism of the transmitter named Ali ibn Zaid, see [islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/170894/).

As far as its meaning is concerned: Having relations with slaves captured as booty in wars is permissible by consensus. However sexual intercourse can only be had after a waiting period to ensure that her womb is empty, and this is called istibra ( استبراء ). It is based on the hadith:

> عن أبي سعيد الخدري، ورفعه، أنه قال في سبايا أوطاس لا توطأ حامل حتى تضع ولا غير ذات حمل حتى تحيض حيضة
>
> Abu Sa’id Al Khudri traced to Prophet (ﷺ) regarding the captives taken at Awtas:
>
> There must be no intercourse with pregnant woman till she gives birth to her child or with the one who is not pregnant till she has had one menstrual period.
>
> <sup>— [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:2157)</sup>

However there is disagreement among the jurists on acts other than intercourse such as kissing. Some consider it permissible even during the waiting period while others do not.

Answer (score -2):

What is the ruling of forcing female slaves to  marry in Islam?

Comment: This is a new question asked in the answer section. If you want to ask a new question please click on "Ask Question" top right of the site and ask it, also check if this question was asked before, and the answer(s) address the question you have in mind. See also [ask].